# How to show preview of dragged and dropped image in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to show the preview of an image that is dragged and dropped in angular.

hospital.component.html

```
<tab heading="Gallery">

          <div id="drop_zone" (drop)="dropHandler($event)" (dragover)="onDragover($event)">
            <p>drag one or more files to this dropzone</p>
            <img src="" id="imgPreview">
          </div>
</tab>
```

hospital.component.ts

```
 dropHandler(ev){
    console.log("file dropped");
    ev.preventDefault();
    let dataTransfer = ev.dataTransfer.getData('data');
   this.imagepreview= <HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('imgPreview');
    this.imagepreview.src=ev.target.result;

  }
  onDrop(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     console.log("drag and dropped file");
  }
  onDragover(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

When I drag and drop Image into the drop zone,Image src property gets changed to http://localhost:4200/undefined. How to get selected images url in angular?

Comment: Why do you not use cdkDragPreview? https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#customizing-the-drag-preview